# Why can't save data from summernote to DB MySQL in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, summernote

I have text area for summernote like this,,

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>CONTENT ENGLISH</label>
        <textarea name="news[content_english]" class="hide" id="news-content-english"><?php echo $news ? htmlentities($news->content_english) : '' ?></textarea>
        <div id="summernote-news-content-english"></div>
    </div>
```

i use javascript to input to database like this,

```
if ($('#news-content-english').val() !== '') {
        $('#summernote-news-content-english').code($('#news-content-english').val());
    }

$('#form-news')
            .submit(function () {
                var content = $('#summernote-news-content-english').code();
                if (content !== '') {
                    $('#news-content-english').val(content);
                } else {
                    alert('news content can\'t be empty');
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

but I have a problem, when using the text area with summernote the data in that field does not enter while the data that other than using summernote can enter, what's the problem?

i use summernote 0.8.12

Comment: how you debug this? are you getting data from div?

Comment: what is the point of getting the content of summernote, and reassigning it back to itself (if statement)? also why are you trying to apply a `val` to a textarea? why is your textarea `name` an array? where is your post code?

Comment: and just a friendly fyi, even if the user didn't enter any text into summernote, it always has something like `<p></p>` so checking if its empty this way won't work. on backend i use a form validation custom rule that strips tags then checks if it is empty.